# Remove trailing zeroes of time datatype in CQL

Tags: cassandra, cql

Trying to remove trailing zero of arrival_time, the column data type is **Time**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

And I got this:

`station_name | arrival_time
--------------+--------------------
   Wellington | 06:05:00.000000000`

and I need the result to look like this:

`station_name | arrival_time
--------------+--------------------
   Wellington | 06:05:00`

I'm new to CQL, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can't actually do that in Cassandra with the `time` type.  You can however, do it with a `timestamp`.

```
cassdba@cqlsh:stackoverflow> CREATE TABLE arrival_time2 (station_name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, 
    arrival_time time, arrival_timestamp timestamp);
cassdba@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO arrival_time2 (station_name , arrival_time , arrival_timestamp)
    VALUES ('Wellington','06:05:00','2018-03-22 06:05:00');
cassdba@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM arrival_time2;

 station_name | arrival_time       | arrival_timestamp
--------------+--------------------+---------------------------------
   Wellington | 06:05:00.000000000 | 2018-03-22 11:05:00.000000+0000

(1 rows)
```

Of course, this isn't what you want either, really.  So next you need to set a `time_format` in the `[ui]` section of your `~/.cassandra/cqlshrc`.

```
[ui]
time_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

Restart cqlsh, and this should work:

```
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.2 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cassdba@cqlsh> SELECT station_name,arrival_timestamp
    FROm stackoverflow.arrival_time2 ;

 station_name | arrival_timestamp
--------------+---------------------
 Wellington | 2018-03-22 11:05:00

(1 rows)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select station_name, SUBSTRING( Convert(Varchar(20),arrival_time), 0, 9)  As arrival_time
from [Table]
```

Used  following  table and  data format

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ArrivalStation](
    [station_name] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [arrival_time] [Time](7) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT [dbo].[ArrivalStation] ([station_name], [arrival_time]) VALUES (N'Wellington ', N'06:05:00.0000000')
INSERT [dbo].[ArrivalStation] ([station_name], [arrival_time]) VALUES (N'Singapore', N'12:35:29.1234567')
```

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work in Cassandra `InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unknown function 'substring'"`

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE` statement also looks like it's meant for a SQL-based RDBMS.